# Redirect more files (favicons) from root to subfolder

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting, favicon

I have couple favicons in `/favicons/*.*` folder, exactly those files:

```
favicon-16x16.png
favicon-32x32.png
favicon-96x96.png
ms-icon-144x144.png
ms-icon-150x150.png
ms-icon-310x310.png
apple-icon.png
apple-icon-152x152.png
apple-icon-180x180.png
apple-icon-precomposed.png
ms-icon-70x70.png
apple-icon-114x114.png
apple-icon-120x120.png
apple-icon-144x144.png
apple-icon-72x72.png
apple-icon-76x76.png
apple-icon-57x57.png
apple-icon-60x60.png
android-icon-192x192.png
android-icon-144x144.png
android-icon-48x48.png
android-icon-72x72.png
android-icon-96x96.png
android-icon-36x36.png
favicon.ico
```

I want to add to htaccess redirect from root to this subfolder. For example, when there is request to `domain.com/android-icon-36x36.png`, it will load favicon from `/favicons/android-icon-36x36.png`.

I tried this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} .*/favicon-16x16.png [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} .*/favicon-32x32.png [OR]
.
.
.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} .*/favicon.ico
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /favicons/$1 [L]
```

But its not redirecting. How should I change the last line to redirect to the same filename? The current code shows `Internal Server Error`. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your last line to:

```
RewriteRule ^((?!favicons/).*)$ /favicons/$1 [L]
```

To avoid a loop

Comment: You also can change `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} .*/(favicon|ms-icon|apple-icon|android-icon)(-\d+x\d+)?\.png` instead of the whole list ;-)

Answer (score 0):

How would I address favicon.ico itself below?

```
   # Localising favicons
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} .*/(favicon|ms-icon|apple-icon|android-icon)(-\d+x\d+)?\.png [OR]
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} .*/(favicon)?\.ico
   RewriteRule ^((?!favicons/).*)$ /favicons/$1 [L]
   # Localising favicons end
```

not sure about the syntax for favicon.ico, the rest works perfectly.